# When and When not to use [ ] operators with if?

Tags: shell-script, test

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Want Task 1'
read r1 ;
if [ echo "${r1}" | grep -iq "^y" ] ; then
    echo 'Task One Done'

    echo 'Want Task 2 ??'
    read r101
    if [ echo "${r101}" | grep -iq "^y" ] ; then 
        echo 'Task 2 Done'
    fi
fi
```

When I run the above code, it gives me error saying

> [: missing `]'
>   grep: ]: No such file or directory

But when I simply omit out the brackets `[` and `]` the code runs perfect. I know this `[]` is a test command, but I don't know when to use it and when not to.

And also please clarify if I should call this `[]` an "operator" or `test` "command "

Side note, if necessary, I am using Bash in GNOME terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the pipe lets the commands run in different subshells, so you get the error message as both commands (`[` and `grep`) are then incomplete (respective do not work as expected).

If you just want to test the result code of a program you do not need to use `[ … ]` or `test`, you will need those only for more distinct comparison like `[ 1 -gt 2 ]` or `[ "$1" == "$2" ]`.
If you want even more advanced comparisons, like using regular expressions, you would use the command `[[ … ]]`, see [Test Constructs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) 
 and [A Brief Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) in the 'Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide'

Comment: Also, should I call these `[]` operators or test command by naming convention?

Comment: I personally prefer to use `[]` because of the enhanced readability, especially when using several tests chained one after another with `&&` or `||`, but it's up to you. (if I understood your question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion to a script which will do the same:

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p 'Want Task 1 ' 
if [ "${REPLY^}" = Y ] ; then
    echo 'Task One Done'

    read -p 'Want Task 2 ?? '
    if [ "${REPLY,}" = y ] ; then 
        echo 'Task 2 Done'
    fi
fi
```

The default variable for `read` is `$REPLY`. When using `${REPLY^}` you will get the content in uppercase, and with `${REPLY,}` it is in lowercase. As the variable can be empty you need the `"` quotes around it.

If you really want to call an external program like `grep` you can do it like this:

```
read -p 'Want Task 1 ' 
if echo $REPLY | grep -icq ^y ; then
        echo 'Task 1 Done'
fi
```

What actually happen above is that we run a command and if the exit value is not 0, it is true. This example will show it:

```
if /bin/true ; then
    echo We have always the yes hat on
fi
```

And `[` is just a program called `/usr/bin/test`. Look it up under `man test`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `${REPLY}` but why is there a `^` at the end of it as you mentioned `${REPLY^}`? Doesn't `^` mean the starting of string? and also what is `,` in `${REPLY,}`?

Comment: @MultiverseTrip No, in a bash string `${REPLY^}` means uppercase. Most of the time `$REPLY` and `${REPLY}` is just the same, but `$REPLY7` is not the same as `${REPLY}7`.

Comment: @hschou It may be worth editing your answer to include Bash 4.0 as a minimum requirement for `case manipulation`.